# UIColor swift extension w/ class access from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-extensions, bridging

How can I access my darkGray color from objective-c please?

```
@objc
extension UIColor
{
    @objc
    public class Scheme1: NSObject {
        static var darkGray: UIColor! {
            return UIColor(red: 16.0/255.0, green: 16.0/255.0, blue: 19.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But, why should are you using objective-c in swift extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Swift 4's `@objc` inference, `darkGray` must be declared `@objc`:

```
@objc
extension UIColor
{
    @objc
    public class Scheme1: NSObject {
        @objc static var darkGray: UIColor! {
            return UIColor(red: 16.0/255.0, green: 16.0/255.0, blue: 19.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

You can access `darkGray` from Objective-C using `Scheme1.darkGray`.  Objective-C does not support nested classes, so `Scheme1` is exported at the top level.

---

If you *really* want to access `Scheme1` in a namespaced manner even from Objective-C, you can make `darkGray` an instance property and store an instance of `Scheme1` in your extension:

```
@objc
extension UIColor
{
    @objc
    public class Scheme1: NSObject {
        @objc var darkGray: UIColor! {
            return UIColor(red: 16.0/255.0, green: 16.0/255.0, blue: 19.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }

    @objc public static var scheme1 = Scheme1()
}
```

You can access `darkGray` using `UIColor.scheme1.darkGray`.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Works 100% .. and yes, Swift4+